# User created Wiki answer without the necessary rep

Tags: bug, community-wiki

In [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/852441/revisions), this 1-rep user created an answer in a community wiki question. Normally, you need at least 10 site rep to post an answer to a Wiki, but this user doesn't appear to be in a suspension, and was able to answer. Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create wiki post is at 10 rep - 100 rep is for editing CW posts.